# No sound when left and right speakers are at equal volume. Built in Output/headphones

Tags: audio, headphones

Ok I believe I have an unknown issue. Please help.

My built-in output appears to have left and right stereo output channels which I can raise or lower their volume independently.
When the volume of both left and right are equal, I get zero sound output.
When the volumes are NOT equal I get sound but it appears to be in MONO regardless of which side, even when I lower one entirely.

It has been an ongoing issue, I just factory reset my computer and it seemed to finally work properly however the problem just returned and I'm at a loss as to what is going on (I didn't think to check if it was mono or stereo at the time it appeared to be working) .

I am a music producer and I need stereo output in order to mix and produce. I'm forced to bounce my projects and upload them to my phone just to be able to hear the stereo mix.

I would really rather not have to buy a new computer to fix this problem. Please help if you have any suggestions.
My headphones are Sony MDR-7508 and my OS is Catalina 10.15.5

Thanks :)

Comment: Is this also the same with a simple sound source like iTunes, playing a 'purchased' tune? Your issue sounds like you have both a sum to mono **and** a 180° phase reverse on one channel. If you have a pro audio rig, you're going to have to diagnose that yourself, so test iTunes first. If iTunes does it too, then check your routing in audio midi setup, Loopback, SoundFlower, or anything else you have that's non-Apple in your I/o chain

Comment: So when I listen to itunes, it seems like I do get sound when the L/R are equal but it phases out a lot of the sound including the voice (the reverb gets through...).
What does get through sounds distorted and super wet.

I use a MacPro. It's the cylinder shaped tower desktop.
I currently have not reinstalled Loopback yet.

Maybe I can get a new interface and route my audio output there. Maybe its the headphone port on the desktop?

Comment: If you are using headphones you will never get cancellation with inverted phase, you will only hear everything as though it's "outside your head". You do need to trace your signal path to find where this is happening. Check things like Loopback are not interfering - uninstall anything like that if needs be to eliminate it as a source. As you're pro audio you're going to have to track it down yourself, as you'll have far more potentially in-circuit than a non-specialist user, any of which could be responsible - hence the iTunes test, to bypass most of any pro audio rig except the output stages.

Comment: I solved the problem but not from fixing the issue.
I got a new audio interface and I route the output through that and plug my headphones in there. L/R works fine now. Thanks for your help :D